# KeePass and Mono - HowTo run on my Mac

Tags: macos, keepass, mono-framework

I'm trying to get KeePass (v2.20.1) running with Mono (v2.10.10) on my Mac running OS X 10.8.2

The KeePass that I've downloaded from http://keepass2.openix.be is NOT a KEEPASS.EXE file as mentioned in earlier posts above, but seems a Mac application and when clicked states something like:

> You have no permission to open Keepass 2.20.1" ( I have a Dutch interface )

I've tried running the Windows .exe but without result, can someone tell me how I can get KeePass running on my Mac?

Comment: Any reason for not using [KeePassX](http://www.keepassx.org/)?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the developer made a mistake when creating the disk image for KeePass for OS X. Your user does not have any permissions for the application bundle to run it or copy it off the disk image.

Remove anything you might have already copied first. Then, after you mount the image (and see the "To install, drag …" instructions), open Terminal, and enter the following:

```
sudo cp -r /Volumes/KeePass2.20.1/KeePass2.20.1.app /Applications
sudo chmod u+wrx /Applications/KeePass2.20.1.app
sudo chown -R $( whoami ):staff /Applications/KeePass2.20.1.app
```

You'll get asked for your password after the first command. You need to be a computer administrator to perform these steps.

Comment: Thank's for your input, and it took me a bit further.

I now have a KeePass2.20.1.app file in the applications folder that is 4.x Mb large ( the old one was 0kb ) but when I try to run it, it seems to start, but then does nothing.

I tried running it from the Terminal by entering mono keepass2.20.1 and some variations on that, but no result.

Any more ideas / suggestions ?

Comment: @Robert It's a Mac application bundle, i.e. a folder that only looks like a file in Finder. You can right-click it and select *Show Package Contents* to view the contents in Finder. You can see the actual `mono` call in `KeePass2.10.1.app/Contents/MacOS/startkeepass.sh`, which is in the same folder where `KeePass.exe` and all auxiliary files reside as well.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing problems with running the keepass bundle downloaded from openix.be (I've tried on Mac OS X Snow Leopard - 10.6.8). The only way to run the original keepass on Mac was to download Mono framework ([www.mono-project.com](http://www.mono-project.com)) for Mac, download the latest keepass.exe from the original site (http://keepass.info/download.html) by selecting the portable .zip package, decompress the .zip on my mac, and run "mono keepass.exe" from the Terminal application.

Unfortunately I've found some problems with copy-and-paste, which is not currently supported in mono for Mac. In the latest version (2.22) the "copy password" button works, but any other function based on copy-and-paste (i.e. Cmd-C / Cmd-V) will not work.

I resolved my issues by using [KeepassX](http://www.keepassx.org/) (version 2.0 alpha 4), which appears to have less functions, but is natively integrated in OsX and copy-and-paste works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, until I found out that preventing KeePass to connect to the Internet (via firewall) solves the issue. Now it starts and it stays open. Give it a try.