# KeePass on Mac OSx does not run

Tags: mac, osx-mountain-lion, keepass

I have followed previous instructions to get KeePass 2.20 installed on my iMac, OSX 10.8.2 but when you click on the app from the Applications folder it appears to start and then does nothing. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Running Keepass under Mono Framework

Requirements for this to work properly:

- Mono Framework: http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html
- Xquartz: https://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/
- Keepass Binaries from website

Installation:

1. Install Mono Framework
2. Install Xquartz and reboot
3. Extract the binaries into a folder titled “Keepass” in the application directory

Running Keepass under the Mono Framework:

1. Open terminal and switch directories to /applications/keepass (cd /d applications/keepass)
2. Type “Mono keepass.exe”
3. Keepass will open under the mono framework

OR

Create a workflow script that acts as app that launches Keepass under mono (I have done this successfully, which is extremely easy if you use the "automator" app.

Issues: While running software under Mono, I have experienced a "delay" in key entry which results in incorrect key entries. This becomes an issue when you are logging into the database or manually assigning a password to an account.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Still it was very slow, took me minutes messing around moving a window saying it wanted to update and waiting while nothing happened.  Running an EXE with `mono Keepass.exe` was the key.  Simple, just not normal for mac I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problems with the .app bundle found on openix.be site. Try downloading mono and keepass 2 zip bundle from http://keepass.info/download.html. Or try [KeepassX](http://www.keepassx.org/).

See also my response at [Keepass for Mac](https://superuser.com/a/596999/225204)

Answer (score -1):

You have to read and follow the instructions provided by the installation program such as installing Mono and XQuartz.

On my Mac it's running well.